# Promise.all resolving earlier than expected

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm writing my first piece of code using Promises and am getting some unexpected results.  I had some code that looked like this (using jQuery):

```
$('.loading-spinner').show();
$('.elements').replaceWith(function() {
   // Blocking code to generate and return a replacement element
});
$('.newElements').blockingFunction();
$('.loading-spinner').hide();
```

To prevent the page getting blocked when this code it run, I tried using setTimeout and Promises to make it asyncronous, like this:

```
$('.loading-spinner').show();
var promises = [];
var promises2 = [];
$('.elements').each(function(i, el){
    promises[i] = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(el).replaceWith(function() {
                // Code to generate and return a replacement element
            });
            resolve(true);
        }, 100);
    });
});
Promise.all(promises).then(function(values) {
    $('.newElements').each(function(i, el) {
        promises2[i] = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(el).blockingFunction();
                resolve(true);
            }, 100);
        });
    });
});
Promise.all(promises2).then(function(values) {
    $('.loading-spinner').hide();
});
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that once the Promises in `promises` are resolved, the Promises in `promises2` are instantiated. Once these are resolved, the loading spinner is hidden.

The effect I'm getting is that, while the page isn't blocked for as long, The spinner disappears as soon as the all the Promises are set up, not waiting until they're resolved.

I can see that the the `promises2` Promises dont resolve until everything in `promises` is resolved, so I dont understand why this is happening.  I guess this is down to either me not understanding Promises properly, or not understating making code asynchronous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're calling `Promise.all` on `promises2` before you populate it, in fact when you call it it contains an empty array so it calls `Promise.all` on an empty array and thus it resolves immediately without waiting for the promises in `promises`.

---

Quick fix:

```
function delay(ms){ // quick promisified delay function
    return new Promise(function(r){ setTimeout(r,ms);});
}

var promises = $('.elements').map(function(i, el){
    return delay(100).then(function(){
        $(el).replaceWith(function() {
            // Code to generate and return a replacement element
        });
});
Promises.all(promises).then(function(els){
    var ps = $('.newElements').map(function(i, el) {
        return delay(100).then(function(){ 
            $(el).blockingFunction();
        });
    });
    return Promise.all(ps);
}).then(function(){
    $('.loading-spinner').hide();
});
```

We can do better though, there is no reason to fire `n` timeouts for `n` elements:

```
delay(100).then(function(){
    $(".elements").each(function(i,el){ 
        $(el).replaceWith(function(){ /* code to generate element */});
    });
}).
then(function(){ return delay(100); }).
then(function(){
    $('.newElements').each(function(i, el) { $(el).blockingFunction(); });
}).then(function(){
    $('.loading-spinner').hide();
}).catch(function(err){
   throw err;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, your explanation made it crystal clear why it wasn't working as expected.  However, I couldn't get either of your examples to work. The first still made the spinner disappear after the first set of promises were resolved, while the second didn't seem to work at all.  Doing n timeouts for n elements seems to spread the load out and help keep the page responsive.

Comment: @marxjohnson yes you're right, I have a mistake there, fixing. I forgot to return the promises to wait for the second time. Fixed now.

Comment: Great, your "quick fix" solution does the job perfectly, thanks.